# Liveview on Android/QX1 Sony Camera API 2.01 fails

Tags: camera, sony

Using the supplied Android demo from

https://developer.sony.com/downloads/all/sony-camera-remote-api-beta-sdk/

Connected up to the WIFI connection on a Sony QX1. The sample application finds the camera device and is able to connect to it.

The liveview is not displaying correctly. At most, one frame is shown and the code hits an exception in SimpleLiveViewSlicer.java

```
if (commonHeader[0] != (byte) 0xFF) {
    throw new IOException("Unexpected data format. (Start byte)");
}
```

Shooting a photo does not seem to work. Zooming does work - lens is moving. Camera is working fine when using the PlayMemories app directly, so no hardware issue.

Hoping from advice from Sony on this one - standard hardware and demo application should work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide some details of your setup?

1. What version of Android SDK are you compiling with?
2. What IDE and OS are you using?
3. Have you installed the latest firmware? (http://www.sony.co.uk/support/en/product/ILCE-QX1#SoftwareAndDownloads)

---

Edit:
We tested the sample code using a QX1 lens and the same setup as you and were able to run the sample code just fine.

One thing to check is whether the liveview is ready to transfer images.  To confirm whether the camera is ready to transfer liveview images, the client can check “liveviewStatus” status of “getEvent” API (see API specification for details).  Perhaps there is some timing issue due to connection speed that is causing the crash.

Comment: 1. I am compiling with SDK version 19
2. Android Studio / Mac OSX 10.10.3
3. I am using the QX1 with the SELP1650 lens - as I see the firmware page, there are no updates for this lens. Is this correctly read?

Comment: Marlin, do you have any comment on this? From what I can tell, it is not possible to firmware upgrade the QX-1 itself. 

Can you confirm that the android test app does not work with stock QX-1?

Comment: Hi see my answer above.  And you're right about the firmware upgrade, it looks like there is no FW upgrade for the QX1 at this time.